# mysql time and php time not the same

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

When I use `current_timestamp` with MySQL, I get the correct time, but when I use

`$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );`

I get the date with with an hour delay (eg, 4:42 PM is 5:42 PM).
I understood that both function use the server's local time - can someone explain the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: You're certain your MySQL and PHP are on the same server, right? Some hosts put the MySQL on a different server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The global system time will be set via the /etc/localtime file, which will be either a symlink or a copy of a zone file from /usr/share/zoneinfo/ on most systems.  Applications will use this as their default.

PHP can override this in a couple different ways:

1. [date.timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) in php.ini
2. setting the TZ environment variable, e.g. `putenv("TZ=US/Central");`
3. [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function (in PHP >= 5.1.0)

MySQL can override this by running the following query immediately after connecting:

```
SET time_zone = 'US/Central'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are php locale settings, it takes it from php.ini, not from system time

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your PHP server thinks it's in a different time zone or it uses different locale and daylight saving time rules.

Comment: how do i get PHP to give me the default, server time that's listed on server's computer? PHP's date.timezone isn't set